# US Int. keyboard layout Right Alt not working as compose key

Tags: release-juno, keyboard-layout

I have an US layout keyboard. I like to have the umlaut like I had them in Windows (US International Layout) where <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> is an "ö" and so on...

I figured out when I use `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` that I can change to US International layout but the compose key `Right Alt` seems to be not working...

I also found out that every other key I use as a compose key works. Only Right Alt does not.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please help me understand that you want to type Umlaute using the right ALT but its not serving its purpose?

Comment: @Hasan yes I want to type Umlaute with Right Alt but Right alt is not working as compose key.

Comment: Okay, but let me ask something else - In  your settings what keyboard layout you have? Or do you have selected German layout as one your preferred layout?

Comment: Please go to **Settings** > **Keyboard** > Select / Add your layout > Change **Compose key** and tell me if it helps.

Comment: @Hasan unfortunately when I do this he switches back to the normal US Layout and not the International Layout. So this does not work. But thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution (I did the wrong combination before):

1. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`
2. Choose `Generic 105-key PC (intl.)`
3. Choose `English (US)`
4. Choose `English (US) - English (intl., with AltGr dead keys)`
5. Choose `Right Alt (AltGr)`
6. Choose `No compose key`

And that's it :)